# Hide SSID from google and youtube?

Tags: proxy, wifi, vpn, socks, ssid

Seems like google and youtube detect your location via SSID that is attached to every packet sent from your Wi-Fi network.
I tried using VPN but it didnt hide the SSID, then i tried using VPN + SOCKv5 but it didnt hide the SSID.
Then i simply tried let-me-thru.com and it hide my location from google just fine lol.

I am very confused, someone can explain me why is that ?
Also can someone recommend me VPN service that hides your SSID please ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really paranoid, don't use wireless networking.

But what makes you think that SSID is sent over the internet? And even if it were (which it is not), you could just change it and there would be no way to know its location.

Perhaps you meant 'IP', which can e used to find your rough location? You cannot spoof your source IP. A decent proxy will hide it, however.

Comment: I think you dont understand the problem, SSID is sent via the link layer, so i have to use L2TP VPN to hide it.. please someone to confirm am i right ?

Comment: It is sent via the link layer, consumed by the base station and no forwarded via IP to the internet. You can trivially verify this by using network traffic sniffing tools. Non-wireless link layer protocols (ATM, ethernet) do not need or care about SSID and will not carry it themselves. IP does not either. Your success with "let-me-thru" shows that it is not a high-level application layer protocol which is doing it. Therefore, your SSID is not transmitted over the internet! Only your IP, which can be used to locate you!

Comment: Make query on how google locates your latitude even if you use VPN.

Comment: Please provide a network capture file showing your SSID being passed out into the internet, and which protocol layer it appears in given that it will not be ethernet, ATM, IP, TCP or HTTP.

Comment: Google locates your latitude by SSID which resides in link layer and thats it.

Comment: Please provide a network capture file showing your SSID being passed out into the internet, and which protocol layer it appears in given that it will not be ethernet, ATM, IP, TCP or HTTP

Comment: http://www.library.cornell.edu/dlit/ds/links/cit/redrover/ssid/wp_ssid_hiding.pdf

Comment: You are talking about a study of wireless network sniffing. If a google network engineer sat outside your house with a network sniffer, he could see your SSID. The SSID exists **only** in the network segment between your laptop and your wireless base station. If the google engineer cut your phone line or cable or whatever you use to link your house to the internet and put in a listening device, he would not see the SSID. He'd see your IP address, and maybe ATM or ethernet information, but the SSID simply does not get passed out of the wireless segment.

Comment: Ok explain how they get my location when i use VPN + SOCK ?

Comment: I have no idea. Possibly your VPN setup is incomplete (eg. leaking DNS traffic). Possibly they are still seeing cookies from your previous connections. Have you tried plugging your computer directly into your router? Or changing your SSID? Hint: it won't make any difference because your SSID is not sent over the internet, in the same way your ethernet MAC is not, because it would be pointless. You can easily run a traffic sniffer to verify this.